# Problem with a Arithmetico-Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions, formal-power-series

Good afternoon to everyone, I have the following question:

What does the arithmetico-geometric series:

$$S = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} ne^{-nrt}$$

Converge to?

($r > 1$, $t > 1$)

I tried to break it up in the series of the even number and the series of the odd numbers multipliers:
\begin{align*}
S &= e^{-rt} + 2e^{-2rt} + ... \\
\\
S &= S_1 + S_2 \\
\\
S_1 &= (3-2)e^{-rt} + (3-0)e^{-3rt} + (3+2)e^{-5rt} + ... \\
\\
    &= \frac{3e^{-rt}}{1-e^{-2rt}} -2e^{-rt} +\frac{2e^{-5rt}}{1-2e^{-2rt}} \\
\\
S_2 &= 2e^{-2rt} + 4e^{-4rt}+... \\
\\
S_2 &= \frac{2e^{-2rt}}{1-2e^{-2rt}} 
\end{align*}

Hence,

$$ S =\frac{2(e^{-5rt}+e^{-2rt})}{1-2e^{-2rt}} + \frac{3e^{-rt}}{1-e^{-rt}}-2e^{-rt} $$

But honestly, I'm not sure at all... Plus I bet $1\$$ that I made some computational mistake...

Ok, now I see it. I've never integrated / differentiated a series before...

\begin{equation*}
S = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} ne^{nrt} \\
\end{equation*}

Let $e^{-rt}=x$.

\begin{align*}
S &= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} nx^n\\
\\
  &= x\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} nx^{n-1} \\
\\
  &= x\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\partial S_1}{\partial x}
\end{align*}

It follows that it must be:

\begin{align*}
 S_1 &= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} x^n
     &= \frac{x}{1-x}
\end{align*}

Hence,

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial S_1}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
\end{equation*}

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
S &= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \\
\\
  &= \frac{e^{-rt}}{(1-e^{-rt})^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hint: differentiate 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n =\frac{1}{1-x}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Minor qualm about your query.  You posted $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} ie^{-irt}.$  Typically, when mathematicians see an expression like $e^{-irt},$ they will automatically (at least) suspect that the $i$ in the exponent specifically refers to $\sqrt{-1}.$  Here, **if** that is the case, then the variable $i$ is being **overused** because it **also** is being used to represent the index of summation.  In such a situation, to avoid any confusion, best to use some other variable for the index of summation.  Then, no one will confuse (for example) $e^{-krt}.$

Comment: @use2661923 Changed notation

Comment: That's not geometric, it's [arithmetico–geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico–geometric_sequence).

Comment: Further to @user2661923's general tip, $j$ may create the same confusion.

Comment: Ok, thank you @J. G., correct.

Comment: Thank you @DonaldSplutterwit

Answer (score 2):

You can see that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n x^n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty x^n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{1-x} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
Now it is just a matter of replacing $x$ with $e^{-rt}$.